# How to: If text in two columns match, copy and paste text from 3 different match row columns to corresponding 3 search row columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAeIs.png)

Any idea how to write an excel formula, program for the following issue?

If the PARENTID in a column B row matches a DOC ID in a column A row, I want excel to copy the columns C, D, and E information for the column A row to the corresponding column B row?

Example: upon recognize that B3 matches A2, excel copies the text of cells C2, D2 and E2 to C3, D3, and E3.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for `C3` is

```
=INDEX(C$2:C2,MATCH($B3,$A$2:$A2,0))
```

You can copy/paste it in all the empty cells (C4, C5, E3, E4, E5).

If you want something that automatically detects where to insert the formula and where to leave an already existing value, you need some VBA.